# How to subtract a column values conditional on another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where I want to substract q.ret of quartile 4  from q.ret of quartile 1 for every index value:
Below is my code to do the task:

```
q8<-  q7%>%  group_by(Index)%>%  summarise(ls =(subset(q7,quartile==1,select=c(q.ret))-subset(q7,quartile==4,select=c(q.ret))))
```

But it gives the following error

```
Error: expecting a single value
```

Please suggest something how to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: I posted a solution.  Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this should work

```
q7%>%  
  group_by(Index)%>%  
  summarise(val =q.ret[quartile==1]-q.ret[quartile==4])
```

---

The `subset(q7,` part is getting the value of 'q.ret' (where `quartile==1`) based on the entire dataset and not within each 'Index'.  For that we just need to subset 'q.ret' based on the logical index (`quartile ==1` or `quartile == 4`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, dear. this is the quickest response I got on SO.